# How to post on multiple pages using django

Tags: python, html, django

For a project, we are trying to build a basic forum-like website; however, we are trying to post on multiple pages instead of one and cannot add another extend on the part that allows the post to be added to that page:

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
{% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to make the website display these posts on multiple pages using another method?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about the "include" keyword? and the "with" template tag?

**post_template.html**

```
<div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
{% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
```

**some_page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% with some_post as post %}{% include "post_template.html"%} {% endwith %}
```

**other_page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% with some_other_post as post %}{% include "post_template.html"%} {% endwith %}
```

Comment: What file would I link instead of the some_post placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want the posts to display, assuming you're passing a list of dicts called `posts`:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% include 'templates/post.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

In `templates/post.html`:

```
<div class="post">
    {% if post.published_date %}
        <div class="date">
            {{ post.published_date }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
</div>
```

See: [How do you insert a template into another template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985950/how-do-you-insert-a-template-into-another-template)