# How can you define basic generic code blocks and insert them in other templates in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, generics

I want to make my HTML site consist of single generic modules kind of like this pseudo-code.

```
{% block body %} // Just a block inside the base html template file
    <div class="container_main">
        {% block generic_sub_menu %} // This should be replaced with a generic submenu, which is defined in another html template file
        {% endblock %}

        Blah Blah Blah

        {% block generic_map_display %} // This should be replaced with a generic map display, which is defined in another html template file
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, I know how to use a base template and insert the body of a more specific template, which extends the base template. But how can I make a template which can be used everywhere with some generic HTML code which is not extending a specific template, but can be used to import some blocks of generic code by other templates?

Is there a way to do this with blocks or do I have to research about some other technique in the Django Framework?

Comment: It would be better if give some example on what you want to achieve. You question is not clear to me.

Comment: I do not really have any example for it since I do not know how to accomplish this. But what should happen is, that the two block statements inside the whole body block should be replaced with html code found in another html template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a file inside the template directory of your project  templates/message_display.html having following code in it

```
    {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                    <div>
                        <h5> {{ message }} </h5>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

So above code is for displaying messages like success or warning message, Now we can use it at any place in any template with following code

```
    {% include "message_display.html" %}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for thank you. But if I had a lot of 'modules' there would be a lot of files, which makes editing and using those a bit more complex when the project grows. So is there a way to compress the files into one or something like that?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking but clearly, you are looking for best approach to manage your Django project. For this, I would suggest you to search "django best practices" and if possible read "Two scoops of Django" book

Comment: Thank you for the advices. What I ment was, if I just use the include statement I would need a seperate file for each block of code I want to include, right? Which would mean if I want a message_display, map_display, message_writer, message_list and so on I would need to create a file for each of them, but that would get messy if I had a lot of them, so I wanted to know wether you know a solution in which a single file contains all of the code, but still can be included just partially.

Comment: you can make one directory inside your template directory ( say snippets ) dedicated for these small code block then later you can use {% include "snippets/message_display.html" %}  or {% include "snippets/map_display.html" %}  It would be neater I think.

Comment: That is what I will be doing, might still be a bit messy when I open it in an editor, but it is the best option I currently have. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the common html code in static folder

if your settings.py has the below line

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

you have to create a folder with your app name as name and inside that you have to keep your file

and in your template file you have to call

```
<script src="{% static "<appname>/<file name>" %}"></script>
```

Also to call one template from other template you have to use below piece of lines in your template

```
<div class="basic">
{% include "main/includes/subtemplate.html" %}    
</div>
```

Refer [How do you insert a template into another template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985950/how-do-you-insert-a-template-into-another-template) for more details

Comment: I know how to do that and this is actually already happening with the base.html and index.html file (index.html is extending the base.html), but what I want to do is import code from a file, for example, generic.html which should contains blocks of code for specific uses.

Comment: Thank you, this was the behaviour I was looking for.

Comment: I know but you and karansthr have the same solution and I can only mark one comment as the answer and upvoting is not possible with a reputation below 15.