# include a terraform template in another template

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have many template files that are used by terraform scripts, all template files have some common part, ie:

```
file a.tmpl:

env=prod
var=a
-------------------
file b.tmpl:

env=prod
var=b
```

I would like to export the common part to a separate file, so that it won't have to repeat in every file, something like:

```
file base.tmpl:
env=prod
-------------------
file a.tmpl:

%{ include "base.tmpl" }
var=a
-------------------
file b.tmpl:

%{ include "base.tmpl" }
var=b
```

but that feature doesn't exists

(it is very similar to `django` templates feature as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10985987/245024)

is there a way to do the include somehow?

---

I was able to do a workaround by concating the files like this:

```
data "template_file" "vars_a" {
  template = "${format("%s \n %s", 
    file("${path.module}/base.tmpl"), 
    file("${path.module}/a.tmpl")
   )}"
}
```

but that is more limiting then including the base template directly in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html):

**a.tmpl**

```
${file("base.tmpl")}
var=a
```

**base.tmpl**

```
var_ddd=ffff
var_sss=adfs
```

**main.tf**

```
data "template_file" "vars_a" {
  template = templatefile("a.tmpl", {})
}

output "test" {
  value = data.template_file.vars_a.template
}
```

Comment: This can be cleaned up by removing the `data "template_file"` resource, as the data resource and the function do the same thing with different approaches. The content of `output "test"` should instead be `value = templatefile("a.tmpl", {})`